# Flyback transformer simulation

Tags: power-supply, transformer, power-electronics, flyback

When I'm using a BJT for switching the flyback transformer, I"m getting the desired current waveform across the primary, but when I'm using a MOSFET, I'm getting a pulse signal as the current waveform across the primary. What could be the reason for that?

[image]

Comment: Your gate voltage is probably not high enough to turn on the FET

Comment: You were told in your previous question to use a base resistor. Look at the difference in current ranges - that gives a big clue and also, please do try to keep comparison times bases approximately equal.

Comment: BJT's are current-controlled devices; E-C conducts *beta (Hfe)* times the base current.  Without a base resistor, huge currents can go into the base, yielding unrealistic results. Building the circuit without a base resistor would likely fail and catch fire.  MOSFETs are voltage-controlled; a gate resistor is not needed (but is sometimes used for switching noise reasons.)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the default NMOS, which is meant to be used for monolithic technology. That's not meant for high current usage. If you want a power switch then you have to either supply your own model, or use one from the existing database (<kbd>RClick</kbd> on the NMOS, choose *Pick New MOSFET*, then select one of the VDMOS listed. You could also use a `.subckt`, but I suspect that, for your case, the existing database should be enough (please correct me if I'm wrong). The same thing does not apply to the diode or the BJT, because their parameters are different. If you need more details, see the help under *LTspice > Circuit Elements > D / M / Q* (D for diode, M for MOSFET/VDMOS, Q for BJT).

As mentioned in the comments, driving the transistors should be done with resistors. In simulation, you don't need to worry about burning devices, but you really shouldn't rely on that, since the results can be influenced by improper driving.